# How to convert the date format from one to another in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format

I have  a column with the date format as **Tue, 29 May 2012 16:04:05 EDT**

I want to convert this format to the this format:29-05-2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: Store date/times using native formats.  Then use `convert()` to put them in whatever format you want when you output them.

Comment: Suggest you review date/time functions in SQL Server first and attempt to write code or at least share any code you have written.

Comment: shows not much effort please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PARSE(REPLACE('Tue, 29 May 2012 16:04:05 EDT', 'EDT', '')AS datetime USING 'en-US')AS [Date&Time];
```

OR

```
 SELECT dateadd(HH, +4, parse(substring('Tue, 29 May 2012 16:04:05 EDT', 1, 25)    as datetime))
```

Comment: Hi Guys, I meant to convert the date format for the whole column in SQL Server

Comment: my answer is not satisfies ur requirement..@RameshGarimella

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @EDTtext varchar(29),
        @EDTdate date

-- key is remove abbreviation EDT
select @EDTtext = 'Tue, 29 May 2012 16:04:05 EDT' 
select @EDTdate = parse(substring(@EDTtext, 1, 25) as date) 

select format(@EDTdate, 'dd-MM-yyyy') -- format 29-05-2012
```

If you have different timezone than EDT don't forget to offset.

Comment: can you explain what the GMT/EDT offset has to do with wanting to change the format?

Comment: It's bonus. Example of converting datetime (problem is only in abbreviation EDT while converting to datetime) and change EDT to GMT.

Comment: bonus? How its it a bonus if it has nothing to do with the requirement? If what was wanted was a change to the format of the date component, how is converting the time component to GMT anything to do with it? The requirement was to change the current date string into a dd-MM-YYYY format